# logback.xml - Detecting directory separator dynamically

Tags: java, spring, operating-system, logback

is there any ways to detect the separator dynamically in logback.xml file? Currently when I set the directory as 
`<file>${app.log.folder}\\general\\general.log</file>`, and this ends up with files titled general\general.log rather than any folders on linux. so is it possible to have something like ${os.separator} property generated automatically? without dynamic detecting testing becomes painful as we need to change the configs manually

Comment: @shekharsuman i had tagged it (spring, and assumed that it would give enough insights that it was java) but somehow it was removed...

Answer (score 4):

You can try ${file.separator}. Look at my code:

```
<file>${catalina.base}${file.separator}logs${file.separator}${logFileName}.log</file>
```

Comment: works perfectly for me.

       <file>${LOGGING_PATH}${file.separator}app.${bySecond}.log</file>